# ¿Alguien sabe como ejecutar un script para activar un entorno de conda, lo he intentado de mil maneras pero no lo consigo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, shell-script

Pues es eso estoy intentado ejecutar un entorno de conda pero me es imposible el comando del script es este:

```
#!/bin/bash 

conda activate base
```

Y este es el error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

   conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Sé que es sencillo el codigo pero no consigo que mediante un script funcione

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar tu script usando `source tu_script` o bien `. tu_script`, en lugar de `./tu_script` como probablemente estás haciendo

Answer (score 0):

El error es más o menos autoexplicativo. Intentas correr `activate base` pero conda te dice que no se han configurado previamente algunas cosas y necesita que ejecutes antes `conda init <SHELL_NAME>`.

Digamos que usas bash como suele ser el caso normalmente. Entonces, deberían correr `conda init bash`. Lo que esto hace es configurar algunas variables de entorno (en el archivo `.bashrc`, posiblemente). Si ejecutas tu script de conda activate con otro usuario, deberás garantizar que ese usuario también tenga acceso a esas variables de entorno (`.bashrc` está en `/home/<tu_usuario>` normalmente). Ya verás si las defines en /etc/profile o alguna otra cosa.

Si al correr manualmente `conda activate` te funciona, lo último que podría proponerse es que le hagas explícito a bash que quieres correr tu script de forma interactiva

```
bash -i tu_shell_script.sh
```

Para que bash entienda que corre de forma interactiva y, por ello, haga `source` de tu `.bashrc` y cargue lo que conda necesita y espera.

Fuente: [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507519/python-activate-conda-env-through-shell-script)